# Как вывести первое попавшееся пустое значение из массива php

Tags: php, массивы

Как вывести первое попавшееся пустое значение из массива, расположение переменных может меняться, в данном примере нужно вывести только array["photo2"]

```
Array
(
    [photo1] => image1.jpg
    [photo2] => 
    [photo3] => 
    [photo4] => image4.jpg
    [photo5] => 
)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если то именно пустая строка

```
echo array_search('', $arr, True); // photo2
```